# ¿Qué sucede cuando Python encuentra una invocación de función?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
nombreFunción(argumento)
```

En mi lectura me menciona estos pasos:

1. Primero, Python comprueba si el nombre especificado es **legal** (explora sus datos internos para encontrar una función existente del nombre; si esta búsqueda falla, Python cancela el código).
2. En segundo lugar, Python comprueba si los requisitos de la función para el número de argumentos **le permiten invocar** la función de esta manera (por ejemplo, si una función específica exige exactamente dos argumentos, cualquier invocación que entregue solo un argumento se considerará errónea y abortará la ejecución del código).
3. Tercero, Python **deja el código por un momento** y salta dentro de la función que se desea invocar; por lo tanto, también toma los argumentos y los pasa a la función.
4. Cuarto, la función **ejecuta el código**, provoca el efecto deseado (si lo hubiera), evalúa el (los) resultado(s) deseado(s) y termina la tarea.
5. Finalmente, Python **regresa al código** (al lugar inmediatamente después de la invocación) y reanuda su ejecución.

Duda:
No logro comprender el punto "3)" cuando dice que los pasa a la función.
Siento que hace referencia a cuando tienes x=3 y luego lo aplicas a f(x)=x+2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno parece que te han dado una explicación simplificada de todo el proceso pues hay muchas cosas mas que pasan al ejecutar tu código. pero aquí vamos a centrarnos en el punto numero 3, que es el que tienes dudas.

### funciones

Las funciones son bloques de códigos, mayormente se usan para reutilizar el código y mantener una estructura modular.

Al ejecutar tu código y declarar una función Python simplemente lo *almacena* para su posterior uso. Por eso se indica que las funciones *callables* lo que quiere decir que se **llaman**, las funciones también tienen parámetros, los cuales se pasan al momento de **llamar** a la función. Ejemplo

```py
#se crea una nueva funcion
def saludo():
    print("Hola!")

#se llama a la funcion
saludo()
```

Aquí lo que Python hace es, NO detiene el resto del código, solo que primero ejecuta la función y espera a que esta termine, luego sigue con el resto de la ejecución del código.  si nosotros modificamos un poco el codigo podemos ver eso.

```py
print("inicio")

#se crea una nueva funcion
def saludo():
    while True:
        print("Hola")

#se llama a la funcion
saludo()

print("adios")
```

Lo que pasara aquí es que primero se ejecutara el `print("inicio")` luego se llamra a la función y esta ejecutara el bucle `while True` (que es infinito), y nunca se ejecutara el `print("adios")` (si ocurre una excepción se detendrá el programa e igual no lo ejecutara).

A las funciones también se le pueden pasar parámetros, para hacer operaciones con estos. Ejemplo:

```
def sumar(a,b):
    return a+b

print("aqui vamos a sumar")

resultado = sumar(2,4)

print(resultado)
```

Aquí declaramos una función la cual recibirá 2 parámetros `a` y `b` y retornara `a+b`, estas son variables propias de la función, es decir que solo existe dentro de la función. Al llamar a la función tendrás que pasarle esos parámetros obligatoriamente , de lo contrario de tara un error. La función recibirá estos parámetros y hará la operación correspondiente con esos valores. lo puedes ver de esta forma

```
f(a,b) = a+b
```

En Python pasa algo curios y es que tu puedes guardar la funcion en una variable y luego ejecutarla. Ejemplo

```py
def sumar(a,b):
    return a+b
#no se usa paréntesis, solo se asigna la funcion a la variable suma
suma = sumar

suma(2+4)
```

Creo que esta explicación fue suficiente para que entiendas lo que pasa, si algo no te quedo claro avísame y añadiré mas explicación y ejemplos :).